# Selenium 2 driver.findElement()

Tags: java, webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver

How is it possible that

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id*='supplierOps_input'][class*='ui-autocomplete-input']"));
```

throw this exception : `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException : Returned node was not an HTML element.`

And

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[id*='supplierOps_input'][class*='ui-autocomplete-input']"));
```

works well and his `.size()` return 1 (so i have only 1 element) and i can get the id value using `.get(0).getAttribute("id");`

My brain struggles.

---

Update :

this is the Selenium part in the POM.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api-2.5</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Which version of Selenium do you use?

Comment: My guess is: Because you search also `class` in the Css selector - by default, there can be more than one element with such class and thats why the findElement fails. But this is really a guess

Comment: Have you tried converting this to it's equivalent XPath query? I'm wondering if it returns the same thing.

Comment: @skirsch Actually i spot that i don't have any `<version>selenium's version</version>` in my `pom.xml`

Comment: @Arran i've answered my own question.

Comment: @e1che so which artifact did you include?

Comment: Do you use a parent pom? Or did you declare a `<dependencyManagement>` element in your pom? Usually, maven fails to build if you don't specify a version...

Comment: @skirsch I've a `<dependecyManagment>` but there is nothing about Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Okay my brain hurts again because 2 days after this question i've tried to do the same thing, a `findElement(By.cssSelector())` and a `findElements(By.CssSelector())` and both works well now.

I've also tried with xpath and works well too, like :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'supplierOps_input') and contains(@class,'ui-autocomplete-input')]"))
```

**This is probably not a real answer** because i can't find why the hell my 1st attempt with cssSelector returned me a throw : `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException : Returned node was not an HTML element.`

Maybe it's unstable sometimes it will be cool and other it will throw..

Comment: Did you run it against the same, unchanged web site?

Comment: @skirsch yes i've changed nothing except the `findElement()`